# Java desktop client does not send message to android emulator

Tags: android

I am developing a client server application. My client is a java application and my server is an android emulator. I want to send message from client to server but no message received on android emulator.
Java Desktop Client Code

```
Socket s = null;
    BufferedReader get = null;
    PrintWriter put = null;
    try {
         s = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 6000);




        put = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);



        put.println("hi");

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {

    }
```

Android Server Code

```
private ServerSocket serverSocket;

Handler updateConversationHandler;

Thread serverThread = null;

private TextView text;
```

private EditText textbox;

```
public static final int SERVERPORT = 6000;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);
    updateConversationHandler = new Handler();
    this.serverThread = new Thread(new ServerThread());
    this.serverThread.start();
}
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    try {
        serverSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

class ServerThread implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        Socket socket = null;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            try {
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                CommunicationThread commThread = new CommunicationThread(socket);
                new Thread(commThread).start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

class CommunicationThread implements Runnable {

    private Socket clientSocket;

    private BufferedReader input;

    public CommunicationThread(Socket clientSocket) {

        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;

        try {

            this.input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.clientSocket.getInputStream()));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run() {


        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

            try {

                String read = input.readLine();

                updateConversationHandler.post(new updateUIThread(read));

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}

class updateUIThread implements Runnable {
    private String msg;

    public updateUIThread(String str) {
        this.msg = str;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        text.setText(text.getText().toString()+"Client Says: "+ msg + "\n");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relevant quote from the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html) (scroll down to the section for *Network Address Space*:

```
Each instance of the emulator runs behind a virtual router/firewall service 
that isolates it from your development machine's network interfaces and settings
and from the internet. An emulated device can not see your development machine
or other emulator instances on the network. Instead, it sees only that it is
connected through Ethernet to a router/firewall.

The virtual router for each instance manages the 10.0.2/24 network address
space — all addresses managed by the router are in the form of 10.0.2.<xx>,
where <xx> is a number. Addresses within this space are pre-allocated by the
emulator/router as follows:
```

And then they proceed to show the pre-allocated addresses in a table.